# DataGridView validation doesn't work

Tags: c#, validation, datagridview, focus

I have a problem with validating a `dataGridView` Cell. Everything works fine unless I press a button (Save data button), that lies outside of `dataGridView` (`dataGridView` loses its focus, and before it validates, the button is pressed).

What I need is that button (and all other controls, including `tabControl`) cannot be focused and pressed until the value on `DataGridView` cell will be validated. Can anyone help please?

Below is code example

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex > 0) // I only validate columns 1,2,3....
        {
            try
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = Convert.ToDouble(e.FormattedValue);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                dataGridView1.CancelEdit();
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable that save button in this code and then enable it back when the validation is over. Show a progess bar or a status bar to denote that there is a postprocessing of data going on. Keep the datagridview focussed all the time while the processing is on. You can do it by having a flag ( bool flag) and setting it to true when this is happening and in mouse move and keypress, you can check it and keep the focus on datagridview itself.